# How can I use offset function in Excel by adding just the number of column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

This is the sample: [image]

if I add the number for the column must get the content of the column in the get_info column
[image: As you see by entering 2 get 4 in column get_info, entered 5 get 1 and so on]

Comment: Don't use `OFFSET()`, just `INDEX()` will do and won't be volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use INDEX and MATCH:

For Row 2: `=MATCH(B2,$C$1:$F$1)` would lookup the index of the column your value is in. The $ around the range value in C1:F1 will ensure the column headers are static even if you copy the formula down.

Then combine with index: `=INDEX(C2:F2,1,MATCH(B2,$c$1:$F$1))` which retrieves the data from that index.

A nice extra is you could wrap that in =IFNA(formula' "") which will prevent it showing #N/A if you haven't entered a value into a cell in column B.

Comment: Just `=INDEX(C2:G2,B2)` will do in `A2`. Drag down.

Answer (score 0):

This one for `offset` function in excell

```
=offset(B2,0,B2)
```